# Span creates a div on enter

Tags: javascript, html

```js
let todoItems = [{
  title: "new",
  content: [{
    text: "first",
    default: true
  }]
}];

// loadTodoItems();
if (todoItems.length > 0) {
  refreshTodoSpaces();
}

// addEventListener("beforeunload", () => saveTodoItems());

function addTodoSpace() {
  saveInputValues();
  let todoTitle = document.getElementById("todoTitle").value;
  if (todoTitle !== "") {
    todoItems.push({
      title: todoTitle,
      content: [{
        text: "",
        default: true
      }],
    });
    refreshTodoSpaces();
  } else {
    alert("Wprowadź tytuł");
  }
  document.getElementById("todoTitle").value = "";
}

function addLi(index) {
  saveInputValues();
  saveTitle();
  todoItems[index].content.push({
    text: "",
    default: true
  });
  refreshTodoSpaces();
}

function saveInputValues() {
  let todoSpaces = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
  for (let i = 0; i < todoSpaces.length; i++) {
    let inputs = Array.from(todoSpaces[i].getElementsByTagName("input"));
    todoItems[i].content = inputs.map((input) => ({
      text: input.value,
      default: input.className === "default",
    }));
  }
}

function saveTitle() {
  let todoSpaces = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
  for (let i = 0; i < todoSpaces.length; i++) {
    let textArea = todoSpaces[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText;
    todoItems[i].title = textArea;
  }
}

function refreshTodoSpaces() {
  let main = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
  main.innerHTML = "";

  saveInputValues();
  todoItems.forEach((todoItem, index) => {
    let todoSpace = document.createElement("div");
    let title = document.createElement("span");
    title.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    title.role = "textarea";
    title.innerText = todoItem.title;
    let deleteTodoSpaceBtn = document.createElement("button");
    deleteTodoSpaceBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>
      deleteTodoSpace(deleteTodoSpaceBtn)
    );
    deleteTodoSpaceBtn.innerHTML = "&#120;";
    todoSpace.appendChild(deleteTodoSpaceBtn);
    todoSpace.appendChild(title);
    todoItem.content.forEach((element) => {
      let section = document.createElement("section");
      let input = document.createElement("input");
      let changeStatusBtn = document.createElement("button");
      changeStatusBtn.innerHTML = "&#9998;";
      changeStatusBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>
        changeStatus(changeStatusBtn)
      );
      let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
      deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", () => deleteTodo(deleteBtn));
      deleteBtn.innerHTML = "&#120;";
      input.setAttribute("type", "text");
      input.className = element.default ? "default" : "checked"; // Set initial class
      input.value = element.text;
      input.placeholder = "write your task here";
      section.appendChild(input);
      section.appendChild(changeStatusBtn);
      section.appendChild(deleteBtn);
      todoSpace.appendChild(section);
    });

    let addListItemButton = document.createElement("button");
    addListItemButton.innerText = "Add List Item";
    addListItemButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      addLi(index);
    });

    todoSpace.appendChild(addListItemButton);
    main.appendChild(todoSpace);
  });
}

function changeStatus(changeStatusBtn) {
  let sectionOfInput = changeStatusBtn.parentNode;
  let inputToChange = sectionOfInput.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  inputToChange.className =
    inputToChange.className === "default" ? "checked" : "default"; // Toggle class

  saveInputValues(); // Save input values after changing status
  refreshTodoSpaces(); // Refresh the display
}

function deleteTodo(element1) {
  const sectionToDelete = element1.parentNode;
  const todoSpaceToDelete = sectionToDelete.parentNode;

  const todoSpaceIndex = Array.from(
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")
  ).indexOf(todoSpaceToDelete);
  const sectionIndex = Array.from(
    todoSpaceToDelete.getElementsByTagName("section")
  ).indexOf(sectionToDelete);

  if (todoSpaceIndex !== -1 && sectionIndex !== -1) {
    todoItems[todoSpaceIndex].content.splice(sectionIndex, 1);
    refreshTodoSpaces();
  }
}

function deleteTodoSpace(button) {
  let todoSpace = button.parentNode;
  let todoSpaces = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  Array.from(todoSpaces).forEach((element, index) => {
    if (todoSpace === element) {
      todoItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  refreshTodoSpaces();
}

function deleteAll() {
  todoItems = [];
  //saveTodoItems;
  refreshTodoSpaces();
}

// function saveTodoItems() {
//   saveInputValues();
//   saveTitle();
//   localStorage.setItem("todoItems", JSON.stringify(todoItems));
// }

// function loadTodoItems() {
//   const savedTodoItems = localStorage.getItem("todoItems");
//   if (savedTodoItems) {;
//   }
// }
```

```css
.default {
  color: green;
}

.checked {
  color: red;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1vw;
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

p {
  width: fit-content;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

main {
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a a a a";
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 2vw;
  justify-content: center;
}

span {
  left: 20vw;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  width: 15vw;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.3s;
  margin: 2vw 0 2vw 0;
}

section {
  margin: 0.2vw;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1vw;
}

input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: dotted 1px black;
}

input:focus,
span:focus {
  outline: none;
}

textarea {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  height: fit-content;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  background-color: #ffffff00;
  border: 1px solid black;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.308);
}

section button {
  width: 1.5vw;
  height: 1.5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="script.js" defer></script>
  <h1>Todo list</h1>
  <input type="text" id="todoTitle" name="todoTitle">
  <input type="submit" onclick="addTodoSpace()" value="dodaj"></input>
  <input type="submit" onclick="deleteAll()" value="usuń wszystkie"></input>
  <main>

  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I have a problem with my todo app. When I click enter while typing inside of a title span, it creates a div inside it. I want the span to just expand in height and add `<br>`, not create a div. Any help would be appreciated. I even tried using chat gpt but it wasn't helpful.

```
let todoItems = [];

loadTodoItems();
if (todoItems.length > 0) {
  refreshTodoSpaces();
}

addEventListener("beforeunload", () => saveTodoItems());

function addTodoSpace() {
  saveInputValues();
  let todoTitle = document.getElementById("todoTitle").value;
  if (todoTitle !== "") {
    todoItems.push({
      title: todoTitle,
      content: [{ text: "", default: true }],
    });
    refreshTodoSpaces();
  } else {
    alert("Wprowadź tytuł");
  }
  document.getElementById("todoTitle").value = "";
}

function addLi(index) {
  saveInputValues();
  saveTitle();
  todoItems[index].content.push({ text: "", default: true });
  refreshTodoSpaces();
}

function saveInputValues() {
  let todoSpaces = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
  for (let i = 0; i < todoSpaces.length; i++) {
    let inputs = Array.from(todoSpaces[i].getElementsByTagName("input"));
    todoItems[i].content = inputs.map((input) => ({
      text: input.value,
      default: input.className === "default",
    }));
  }
}

function saveTitle() {
  let todoSpaces = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));
  for (let i = 0; i < todoSpaces.length; i++) {
    let textArea = todoSpaces[i].getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerText;
    todoItems[i].title = textArea;
  }
}

function refreshTodoSpaces() {
  let main = document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0];
  main.innerHTML = "";

  saveInputValues();
  todoItems.forEach((todoItem, index) => {
    let todoSpace = document.createElement("div");
    let title = document.createElement("span");
    title.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
    title.role = "textarea";
    title.innerText = todoItem.title;
    let deleteTodoSpaceBtn = document.createElement("button");
    deleteTodoSpaceBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>
      deleteTodoSpace(deleteTodoSpaceBtn)
    );
    deleteTodoSpaceBtn.innerHTML = "&#120;";
    todoSpace.appendChild(deleteTodoSpaceBtn);
    todoSpace.appendChild(title);
    todoItem.content.forEach((element) => {
      let section = document.createElement("section");
      let input = document.createElement("input");
      let changeStatusBtn = document.createElement("button");
      changeStatusBtn.innerHTML = "&#9998;";
      changeStatusBtn.addEventListener("click", () =>
        changeStatus(changeStatusBtn)
      );
      let deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
      deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", () => deleteTodo(deleteBtn));
      deleteBtn.innerHTML = "&#120;";
      input.setAttribute("type", "text");
      input.className = element.default ? "default" : "checked"; // Set initial class
      input.value = element.text;
      input.placeholder = "write your task here";
      section.appendChild(input);
      section.appendChild(changeStatusBtn);
      section.appendChild(deleteBtn);
      todoSpace.appendChild(section);
    });

    let addListItemButton = document.createElement("button");
    addListItemButton.innerText = "Add List Item";
    addListItemButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
      addLi(index);
    });

    todoSpace.appendChild(addListItemButton);
    main.appendChild(todoSpace);
  });
}

function changeStatus(changeStatusBtn) {
  let sectionOfInput = changeStatusBtn.parentNode;
  let inputToChange = sectionOfInput.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  inputToChange.className =
    inputToChange.className === "default" ? "checked" : "default"; // Toggle class

  saveInputValues(); // Save input values after changing status
  refreshTodoSpaces(); // Refresh the display
}

function deleteTodo(element1) {
  const sectionToDelete = element1.parentNode;
  const todoSpaceToDelete = sectionToDelete.parentNode;

  const todoSpaceIndex = Array.from(
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")
  ).indexOf(todoSpaceToDelete);
  const sectionIndex = Array.from(
    todoSpaceToDelete.getElementsByTagName("section")
  ).indexOf(sectionToDelete);

  if (todoSpaceIndex !== -1 && sectionIndex !== -1) {
    todoItems[todoSpaceIndex].content.splice(sectionIndex, 1);
    refreshTodoSpaces();
  }
}

function deleteTodoSpace(button) {
  let todoSpace = button.parentNode;
  let todoSpaces = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  Array.from(todoSpaces).forEach((element, index) => {
    if (todoSpace === element) {
      todoItems.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  refreshTodoSpaces();
}

function deleteAll() {
  todoItems = [];
  saveTodoItems;
  refreshTodoSpaces();
}

function saveTodoItems() {
  saveInputValues();
  saveTitle();
  localStorage.setItem("todoItems", JSON.stringify(todoItems));
}

function loadTodoItems() {
  const savedTodoItems = localStorage.getItem("todoItems");
  if (savedTodoItems) {
    todoItems = JSON.parse(savedTodoItems);
  }
}
```

I've tried everything. I could think of but nothing seems to work.

Comment: The exact behavior of `contenteditable` HTML elements is probably browser-dependent. Google Chrome, for example, generates a `<br>` when I press ENTER in a `<span>`.

Comment: Hi ! Don't forget to [read the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It would be even easier to help you if you made your code a runnable snippet with HTML/JS/CSS. Use the button with `<>` to do just that. Maybe the problem is that you have selectors like this: `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`. You should not select elements by tag name. Rather, give them classes instead and use querySelectorAll()

Comment: @PeterKrebs it doesn't work

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I also use chrome and when I create another website with the same span, it works correctly and creates "<br>" instead of a div